# Derivative Applications Word Problem

Tags: calculus, derivatives

When a space shuttle is launched into space, an astronaut's body weight decreases until a state of weightlessness is achieved. The weight $W$ of a 150 pound astronaut at an altitude of $x$ kilometers above sea level is given by $W = 150{(\frac{6400}{6400+x})}^2$. If the space shuttle is moving away from the earth's surface at the rate of $6 \text{ km/sec}$, at what rate is $W$ changing when $x = 1000 \text{ km}$.

I consider as follows:

- $x$ is given in terms of kilometers.
- $W$ is given as a function of $x : W(x)$
- $\Delta x$ is given to be $6/sec$.

To differentiate W we use $\lim_{\Delta x \to 0}\dfrac{W(x + \Delta x)-W(x)}{\Delta x}$ and find $W'(x) = 300{(\frac{-{6400}^2}{{(6400+x)}^3})}^2$

The instantaneous rate of change for $W$ at $x = 1000$ is given by: $$W'(1000) = 300{(\frac{-{6400}^2}{{(6400+1000)}^3})}^2 = -\frac{1536}{50653} \approx -0.030324$$

So, it would seem to me that the rate of change in $W$ at $x = 1000$ is $\approx -0.030324$.

However, it seems strange to me that the given rate of change in $x$ would be extraneous information in this situation, so I considered perhaps that it was appropriate to consider that rate of change in $W$ at $x = 1000$ to be $W'(1000) \cdot  \Delta x$.

I am uncertain of the proper answer, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second thought is somewhat correct. But it is due to the chain rule. Your first found $W'(1000)=-0.030324$ is not the rate of change of $W$ with respect to time variable $t$, it is rather the change of $W$ with respect to the change of position $x$, if solved correctly. To find $W'(t)$,

$$\frac{dW}{dt}=\frac{dW}{dx}\frac{dx}{dt}=300{(\frac{-{6400}^2}{{(6400+x)}^3})}\frac{dx}{dt}$$

Then when you plug in $x=1000$, you should also plug in $\frac{dx}{dt}=6$.